# Google Chrome third party cookie page is hanging / unresponsive in Linux

Tags: google-chrome, linux

I use Google Chrome in Arch Linux / Sway and have the latest version:
Version 118.0.5993.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Whenever I go to the third party cookie page Chrome hangs and becomes unresponsive. How can I fix this? It's a serious problem because I need to change this setting.

I have already rebuilt and re-installed Chrome twice, so please don't tell me to reinstall it.

Comment: Have you tried incognito mode?

Comment: 1. Are there any extensions to Chrome? If so, disable them or try changing the setting in Incognito mode (which also disables extensions). 2. That version might not be fully adapted for Linux. Consider changing browser, e.g., an older version or try Firefox.

Comment: Furthermore, as always in Linux (and for the most part in any other OS), reinstalling changes nothing because errors seldom if ever are related with the software itself but often with user profiles and/or, in case of web browsers, rogue extensions. The aforementioned suggestions test extensions. If the problem persists in incognito mode then it rules out a problem with said addons so the next logical step is to delete the hidden settings/users profiles folders and start again, no re-installation needed.